# Recovering data remotely from a lost device

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, data-recovery, lost-phone

I was wondering if I could recover some photos and/or contacts from my phone which I lost yesterday.

Also I'm pretty sure it was stolen, so is there a way that I can know when the device is online?

Comment: If the device is on and has data connection you can locate it on https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

Comment: Was your phone signed into one of the "cloud" services?  If you set up your Google account to sync contacts and backup photos, all that information should already be saved.  Log into [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#contacts) on the web and see if your contacts are there. Photos are auto-backed up to Google's [Photos](https://plus.google.com/photos) service if you enabled it.  Similarly, Samsung provides their own cloud backup services, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: If you didn't take any pre-caution measures (like installing an appropriate app for that situation), you will have a hard time "recovering data" from a device you don't have access to. In that case, the best you can hope for is a remote wipe via the Device Manager Dan just mentioned.